# How to increment Primary Keys when emulating the addition and editing of records with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Just discovered an issue with JMeter.

I tried to record a create and edit record session using JMeter. Then replayed it, only to discover that when replaying, the initial record got added again, ok good, but with no data. I then realised that my replay script is actually re-editing the original record that was created when the recording took place ie it was using the old PK record in the querystring, instead of that for the newly created record. All makes sense when you think about it.

So what is the best approach to enable JMeter to use the PK of the record it has just created.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of scripting work (not magically done by jmeter).

You need to locate in request all data that changes and:

- use variables (${varName})
- Use Csv Data Set to extract the variable values from a csv file

If any variable comes from a previous request use Post processorS:

- Regexp for text or html
- JQuery /css extractor for html
- XPath for xml

See reference docs:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html

Comment: Thanks. I get the idea now. Very new to JMeter.